# Many to many lstm implementation - value error

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to train an LSTM for the below inputs and outputs

```
Input       output
(10,20)     (3.43766, -0.0258654, -9.33203)
(20,30)     (3.39076, 0.0415078, -9.29935)
(30,40)     (3.49587, -0.0158063, -9.47972)
```

This is a many to many use case.

My approach

```
X = ((10,20),
    (10,20))
X=(np.array(X))


Y = (
(3.43766, -0.0258654, -9.33203),
(3.39076, 0.0415078, -9.29935))

Y=(np.array(Y))


from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(input_shape=(2,2),return_sequences=True, units=50))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(250,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(3)))
model.add(Activation("linear"))

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="rmsprop")
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=10000, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

I am getting the below error

```
    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_2 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (1, 2)
```

Can anyone help me please

Answer (score 0):

I think `(2,1)` should be the correct input shape:

```
model.add(LSTM(input_shape=(2,1), return_sequences=True, units=50))
```